# Random HTTP 405 Method not allowed

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I have a ASP.NET Core site that is using MVC, and randomly, and not reproducibly is having HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed responses when a client posts to a specific URL on the site.

On the AJAX POST I get back this.

```
{ "readyState": 4, "responseText": "Status Code: 405; Method Not Allowed ", "status": 405, "statusText": "Method Not Allowed" }
```

The AJAX POST request looks like this

```
{
"url": "/Area1/UserController/SaveUserInfo",
"type": "POST",
"isLocal": false,
"global": true,
"processData": true,
"async": true,
"contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"accepts": {
    "*": "*/*",
    "text": "text/plain",
    "html": "text/html",
    "xml": "application/xml, text/xml",
    "json": "application/json, text/javascript",
    "script": "text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"
},
"contents": {
    "xml": {},
    "html": {},
    "json": {},
    "script": {}
},
"responseFields": {
    "xml": "responseXML",
    "text": "responseText",
    "json": "responseJSON"
},
"converters": {
    "text html": true
},
"flatOptions": {
    "url": true,
    "context": true
},
"jsonp": "callback",
"headers": {
    "RequestVerificationToken": "CfDJ8JPmrZ3OGbJBvyR1PkOAgaLxEM_afDFd0EDTn40dQOjE947T6OmM_qAk_TGfwQAWBFfGpNqpYh-QTS4pCdYCFTrF7JZsRuzYrG1GXjKD-dStYg1fMhylaIUuTuZ4Pqalg4HXhTv4n51LoON1XdBfOCDFnjUIW_KeEj4V-xUyD4OvbgSwh07T2jcZRrCd1-qRjw"
},
"cache": false,
"statusCode": {},
"dataType": "json",
"data": "__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8JPmrZ3OGbJBvyR1PkOAgaIAmKPl4WuN41qZTyL-zQ1MKcKFgIKKQd2afSAsQMiM74085vecjzSdxfN5u6v9QA-lPb84_bWp1vhCaHjvkoF8NVGWvSlPgHVAuYY--EBatPmaocCNkpZjmGn7lHrXDPK-2-FfFOPNU11VyVuAoEnosEiW2jAWVvstH0NQPWwHmQ",
"dataTypes": [
    "text",
    "json"
],
"crossDomain": false,
"hasContent": true
}
```

and the controller action that is being posted to is like this

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult SaveUserInfo()
{
    _logger.Debug("Post to SaveUserInfo called");

    // other code here

    return this.NewtonJson(JsonResponseWrapper.Success());
}
```

and the JavaScript that is running this post has this call

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: postUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData,
                success: function success(data) {
                    // do something here
                }
            });
```

Everything seems to be post, the data types seem to all be JSON as produced and expected, what would cause this 405?

Comment: Could you show all codes related? have you tried with preventDefault(); to prevent sending a get request to post endpoint?